# Oracle SQL Developer Textcursor disappearing

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-sql-developer

In the Oracle SQL Developer on my manjaro Linux, the blinking cursor in the editor area won't show anymore. I deleted everything of local config files (~/.sqldeveloper/) and reloads the program. At first, the cursor is visible again but after i pressed the "excute script (F5)"-Button, it will get lost and there seems no way to fix this.

### My setup:

## SQL Developer

Version 4.1.5.21
Build MAIN-21.78

## Java

java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)

## OS

Linux 4.4.39-1-MANJARO

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/message/13669248#13669248

Comment: I never had a blinking cursor when I used SQL Developer.  :-)  This article May help: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3700530?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: Can't answer as question is closed, but changing window size usually resets cursor back to life.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true` to `~/.sqldeveloper/<version>/product.conf` fixed it for me.

Comment: Worked with version 18.3

Comment: Didn't fix the issue for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the cursor gets hidden because of different monitor resolutions. Try to change the font size by going to Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Fonts.